# I want to release some ram space to improve performance of system without terminating or killing java process

Tags: java, linux, process, garbage-collection

I just installed oracle on linux machine but currently am not doing anything on it. still its showing "java" process in top output and it grabbed too much of ram. [as in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xne4g.png)
I want to release some ram space to improve performance of system without terminating or killing java process

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can run garbage collector using System.gc();
But before make sure than in your app's code there are not any reference to object which are no longer used.

Comment: You can give this options to the jvm it's running very well for me: -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20

Answer (score 0):

Your program is using 1.5 GB resident, it's virtual size doesn't matter. A good portion might not be in the heap.

Your machine is using 16.3 GB is cached files. These are discarded as you need more memory.

In short, At it is using ~8% of memory, I don't think it is impacting performance.